# Замена текста в javascript

Tags: javascript

Я подключаюсь к Апи Банка России, они выдают Апи в формате XML мне нужно их переделать в json
Пытаюсь поменять узли XML с помощью replace()

**Вот текст который приходит в запросе**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><ValCurs Date="22.12.2020" name="Foreign Currency Market"><Valute ID="R01010"><NumCode>036</NumCode><CharCode>AUD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Австралийский доллар</Name><Value>56,2729</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01020A"><NumCode>944</NumCode><CharCode>AZN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Азербайджанский манат</Name><Value>43,9506</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01035"><NumCode>826</NumCode><CharCode>GBP</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства</Name><Value>99,0973</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01060"><NumCode>051</NumCode><CharCode>AMD</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>Армянских драмов</Name><Value>14,2982</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01090B"><NumCode>933</NumCode><CharCode>BYN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Белорусский рубль</Name><Value>29,6459</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01100"><NumCode>975</NumCode><CharCode>BGN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Болгарский лев</Name><Value>46,5682</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01115"><NumCode>986</NumCode><CharCode>BRL</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Бразильский реал</Name><Value>14,6338</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01135"><NumCode>348</NumCode><CharCode>HUF</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>Венгерских форинтов</Name><Value>25,2445</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01200"><NumCode>344</NumCode><CharCode>HKD</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Гонконгских долларов</Name><Value>96,3076</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01215"><NumCode>208</NumCode><CharCode>DKK</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Датская крона</Name><Value>12,2425</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01235"><NumCode>840</NumCode><CharCode>USD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Доллар США</Name><Value>74,6721</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01239"><NumCode>978</NumCode><CharCode>EUR</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Евро</Name><Value>91,0029</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01270"><NumCode>356</NumCode><CharCode>INR</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Индийских рупий</Name><Value>10,1265</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01335"><NumCode>398</NumCode><CharCode>KZT</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>Казахстанских тенге</Name><Value>17,7626</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01350"><NumCode>124</NumCode><CharCode>CAD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Канадский доллар</Name><Value>57,9977</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01370"><NumCode>417</NumCode><CharCode>KGS</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>Киргизских сомов</Name><Value>92,4993</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01375"><NumCode>156</NumCode><CharCode>CNY</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Китайский юань</Name><Value>11,4015</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01500"><NumCode>498</NumCode><CharCode>MDL</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Молдавских леев</Name><Value>43,3447</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01535"><NumCode>578</NumCode><CharCode>NOK</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Норвежских крон</Name><Value>85,1508</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01565"><NumCode>985</NumCode><CharCode>PLN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Польский злотый</Name><Value>20,1860</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01585F"><NumCode>946</NumCode><CharCode>RON</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Румынский лей</Name><Value>18,7097</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01589"><NumCode>960</NumCode><CharCode>XDR</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>СДР (специальные права заимствования)</Name><Value>107,8243</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01625"><NumCode>702</NumCode><CharCode>SGD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Сингапурский доллар</Name><Value>55,9216</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01670"><NumCode>972</NumCode><CharCode>TJS</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Таджикских сомони</Name><Value>66,0231</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01700J"><NumCode>949</NumCode><CharCode>TRY</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Турецких лир</Name><Value>96,8309</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01710A"><NumCode>934</NumCode><CharCode>TMT</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Новый туркменский манат</Name><Value>21,3654</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01717"><NumCode>860</NumCode><CharCode>UZS</CharCode><Nominal>10000</Nominal><Name>Узбекских сумов</Name><Value>71,2996</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01720"><NumCode>980</NumCode><CharCode>UAH</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Украинских гривен</Name><Value>26,7474</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01760"><NumCode>203</NumCode><CharCode>CZK</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Чешских крон</Name><Value>34,6619</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01770"><NumCode>752</NumCode><CharCode>SEK</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Шведских крон</Name><Value>89,4898</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01775"><NumCode>756</NumCode><CharCode>CHF</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>Швейцарский франк</Name><Value>84,1471</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01810"><NumCode>710</NumCode><CharCode>ZAR</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>Южноафриканских рэндов</Name><Value>50,4528</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01815"><NumCode>410</NumCode><CharCode>KRW</CharCode><Nominal>1000</Nominal><Name>Вон Республики Корея</Name><Value>67,6421</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01820"><NumCode>392</NumCode><CharCode>JPY</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>Японских иен</Name><Value>72,1086</Value></Valute></ValCurs>
```

**Вот мой код**

```
// Replace XML to Array
                        xmlApi = data
                            .replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>', '')
                            .replace('<ValCurs Date="22.12.2020" name="Foreign Currency Market">', '')
                            .replace('</ValCurs>', '')
                            .replace('<Valute ID="', '{"id":"')
                            .replace('"><NumCode>', '", "num":"')
                            .replace('</NumCode><CharCode>', '", "char":"')
                            .replace('</CharCode><Nominal>', '", "nominal":"')
                            .replace('</Nominal><Name>', '", "name":"')
                            .replace('</Name><Value>', '", "value":"')
                            .replace('</Value></Valute>', '"},')

                        arrayApi = xmlApi;
                        console.log(arrayApi)
```

**Вот что мне вернула консоль**

```
{"id":"R01010", "num":"036", "char":"AUD", "nominal":"1", "name":"������������� ������", "value":"56,2729"},<Valute ID="R01020A"><NumCode>944</NumCode><CharCode>AZN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>��������������� �����</Name><Value>43,9506</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01035"><NumCode>826</NumCode><CharCode>GBP</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>���� ���������� ������������ �����������</Name><Value>99,0973</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01060"><NumCode>051</NumCode><CharCode>AMD</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>��������� ������</Name><Value>14,2982</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01090B"><NumCode>933</NumCode><CharCode>BYN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>����������� �����</Name><Value>29,6459</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01100"><NumCode>975</NumCode><CharCode>BGN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>���������� ���</Name><Value>46,5682</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01115"><NumCode>986</NumCode><CharCode>BRL</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>����������� ����</Name><Value>14,6338</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01135"><NumCode>348</NumCode><CharCode>HUF</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>���������� ��������</Name><Value>25,2445</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01200"><NumCode>344</NumCode><CharCode>HKD</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>����������� ��������</Name><Value>96,3076</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01215"><NumCode>208</NumCode><CharCode>DKK</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>������� �����</Name><Value>12,2425</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01235"><NumCode>840</NumCode><CharCode>USD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>������ ���</Name><Value>74,6721</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01239"><NumCode>978</NumCode><CharCode>EUR</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>����</Name><Value>91,0029</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01270"><NumCode>356</NumCode><CharCode>INR</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>��������� �����</Name><Value>10,1265</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01335"><NumCode>398</NumCode><CharCode>KZT</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>������������� �����</Name><Value>17,7626</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01350"><NumCode>124</NumCode><CharCode>CAD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>��������� ������</Name><Value>57,9977</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01370"><NumCode>417</NumCode><CharCode>KGS</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>���������� �����</Name><Value>92,4993</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01375"><NumCode>156</NumCode><CharCode>CNY</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>��������� ����</Name><Value>11,4015</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01500"><NumCode>498</NumCode><CharCode>MDL</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>���������� ����</Name><Value>43,3447</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01535"><NumCode>578</NumCode><CharCode>NOK</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>���������� ����</Name><Value>85,1508</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01565"><NumCode>985</NumCode><CharCode>PLN</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>�������� ������</Name><Value>20,1860</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01585F"><NumCode>946</NumCode><CharCode>RON</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>��������� ���</Name><Value>18,7097</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01589"><NumCode>960</NumCode><CharCode>XDR</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>��� (����������� ����� �������������)</Name><Value>107,8243</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01625"><NumCode>702</NumCode><CharCode>SGD</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>������������ ������</Name><Value>55,9216</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01670"><NumCode>972</NumCode><CharCode>TJS</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>���������� ������</Name><Value>66,0231</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01700J"><NumCode>949</NumCode><CharCode>TRY</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>�������� ���</Name><Value>96,8309</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01710A"><NumCode>934</NumCode><CharCode>TMT</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>����� ����������� �����</Name><Value>21,3654</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01717"><NumCode>860</NumCode><CharCode>UZS</CharCode><Nominal>10000</Nominal><Name>��������� �����</Name><Value>71,2996</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01720"><NumCode>980</NumCode><CharCode>UAH</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>���������� ������</Name><Value>26,7474</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01760"><NumCode>203</NumCode><CharCode>CZK</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>������� ����</Name><Value>34,6619</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01770"><NumCode>752</NumCode><CharCode>SEK</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>�������� ����</Name><Value>89,4898</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01775"><NumCode>756</NumCode><CharCode>CHF</CharCode><Nominal>1</Nominal><Name>����������� �����</Name><Value>84,1471</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01810"><NumCode>710</NumCode><CharCode>ZAR</CharCode><Nominal>10</Nominal><Name>��������������� ������</Name><Value>50,4528</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01815"><NumCode>410</NumCode><CharCode>KRW</CharCode><Nominal>1000</Nominal><Name>��� ���������� �����</Name><Value>67,6421</Value></Valute><Valute ID="R01820"><NumCode>392</NumCode><CharCode>JPY</CharCode><Nominal>100</Nominal><Name>�������� ���</Name><Value>72,1086</Value></Valute>
```

Отработала замена только в первом узле, остальные не отработали, почему так, что делать

Ссылка на АПИ

```
view-source:http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp?date_req=22/12/2020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод replace срабатывает один раз. Чтобы сработал много, нужно в первом аргументе функции replace вместо строки использовать регулярку с [флагом g](https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-introduction#flagi), или метод [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Comment: data.replaceAll is not a function

Comment: Значит data не является строкой или среда не поддерживает последние нововведения js. Можете найти метод replaceAll в интернете или сделать самостоятельно.

Comment: Если я ставлю replaceAll в браузерном js то он работает как нужно, но если в node.js то он говорит что это не функция, возможно для node есть другой способ?

Comment: Так найдите просто эту функцию. В каком-нибудь npm. Или просто напишите `.split('старая_подстрока').join('новая_подстрока')` или что-то аналогичное.

Comment: Да спасибо огромное Работает!!!